# Protractor Not select first Element from an autocomplete search address

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, selenium, element, protractor

i need to select the first element from an autocomplete search box , 
when autocomplete shows its hover other element,so other element not clickable by protractor ,
solution

element.all(by.css('[ng-model="address"]')).get(0) is not work for me but work in another computer , 
same script work in another computer ,
i checked protractor version , selenium version
i also try  element.all(by.css('[ng-model="address"]')).first() ;
its also not work for me , 
do you have any idea how  cant i get first element ?.
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you can send enter key

protractor.Key.ENTER

yourelement.sendKeys('your text to send  ', protractor.Key.ENTER);

Answer (score 4):

The Autocomplete List is only visible if a curser is over the element.

```
this.selectFirstElement = function(element){
    browser.sleep(3500);
    browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(element);
    element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN);
    element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a short delay (say 500ms) and then do click. Sometimes the rendering of autocomplete misses the first item.